# Unable to export an excel sheet using AbstractExcelView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my ExcelController.java

```
public ModelAndView generateExcel(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    // Created List called 'employeeList'
    model.put("employeeList", employeeList);

    return new ModelAndView("CreateExcel","employeeList",employeeList);
}
```

This is my ExcelRevenueReportView.java

```
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
        HSSFWorkbook workBook, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Employee> employeeList = (List<Employee>) model.get("employeeList");
    HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("Employee List");

    HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Employee");

    int rowNum = 1;
    for (Object employee : employeeList) {
        //create the row data
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        System.out.println(row);
        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(1);
            }
}
```

My servlet.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="com.sort.process.ExcelController" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/spring-excel-views.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

my spring-excel-views.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sort.process" />
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/log4j.properties" />

<bean id="ExcelRevenueSummary"
    class="com.sort.process.ExcelRevenueReportView">
</bean>
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractexcelview/).

In the above project I know that I am not calling the `buildExcelDocument()` and that may be the reason that the excel sheet is not being generated and I ain't sure if I should call it somewhere.
Ultimately, I am unable to generate excel sheet through this way.
Can anyone please spot the mistake?
Or any other possible suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use more lightweight approach with Annotation-based Controllers configuration. In that case just place in you controller the following code:

```
@RequestMapping("list/excell")
public View listExcell() {
    return new AbstractExcelView() {
        @Override
        protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("List of employees");

            setText(getCell(sheet, 0, 0), "Id");
            setText(getCell(sheet, 0, 1), "First name");
            setText(getCell(sheet, 0, 2), "Last name");
            setText(getCell(sheet, 0, 3), "Active");
            setText(getCell(sheet, 0, 4), "Salary");

            List<Employee> employees = dao.listEmployees();
            for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
                Employee employee = employees.get(i);
                setText(getCell(sheet, i + 1, 0), String.valueOf(employee.getId()));
                setText(getCell(sheet, i + 1, 1), employee.getFirstName());
                setText(getCell(sheet, i + 1, 2), employee.getLastName());
                setText(getCell(sheet, i + 1, 3), String.valueOf(employee.isActive()));
                setText(getCell(sheet, i + 1, 4), String.valueOf(employee.getSalary()));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The problem in you code is that in your controller you use view named "CreateExcel", but in your configuration you name your view "ExcelRevenueSummary".

If you need a full working example - you may find it [here](https://github.com/isopov/haf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sopovs/moradanen/haf/controller/employee/EmployeeController.java).

Comment: But now you have intermingled the View and the Controller.  MVC, separation of concerns.

Comment: You can easily do a separate view - just use a named class instead of a anonymous one, and create it using the employees list and not the DAO - that way logic of getting this list will be decoupled from the view.

Comment: Still the generic level can be improved by isolating the layers...
You can find the way from the following link
[link](http://javapapers.com/spring/excel-export-in-spring-mvc/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example [Excel Export Spring MVC](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-excel-view-example-apache-poi-and-jexcelapi).
If you are specific with extentions then you can add the below line's in your code.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BusinessSegment.xls");
```

Now this will export your data in Excel with .xls extention.